# Apache Mina SSHD setKeyPairProvider save generated keys (Android)

Tags: java, android, apache, ssh, sshd

In Apache Mina SSHD Github documentation https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd#configuring-the-server-instance we can see section **"KeyPairProvider"**.

In this section we can see

> It's usually a good idea to save generated keys, so that if the SSHD
>   server is restarted, the same keys will be used to authenticate the
>   server and avoid the warning the clients might get if the host keys
>   are modified.

My question is **how to save generated keys** because every time when I make restart server in Terminal I can see message

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
```

And I need to go in /.ssh/known_hosts and delete for IP address generated "sha-rsa" key.

I tried few ways

1.) Way

```
if(SecurityUtils.isBouncyCastleRegistered()){
   PEMGeneratorHostKeyProvider hostKeyProvider = new PEMGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("myapp.pem").getAbsolutePath());
   hostKeyProvider.setAlgorithm("RSA");
   sshd.setKeyPairProvider(hostKeyProvider);
}else{
   SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider hostKeyProvider = new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("myapp.ser").getAbsolutePath());
   hostKeyProvider.setAlgorithm("RSA");
   sshd.setKeyPairProvider(hostKeyProvider);
}
```

2.) Way

First generate "keystore" file.

> keytool -genkey -keystore "app.keystore" -keyalg RSA

```
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider("app.keystore", "RSA"));
```

3.) Way

```
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider("hostkey.ser"));
```

4.) Way

First generate "PEM" file.

> openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365000 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout
>   app.crt -out app.crt
>
> openssl pkcs12 -export -in app.crt -out app.p12
>
> openssl pkcs12 -in app.p12 -out app.pem

```
PEMGeneratorHostKeyProvider hostKeyProvider = new PEMGeneratorHostKeyProvider(new File("app.pem").getAbsolutePath());
hostKeyProvider.setAlgorithm("RSA");
```

or

```
PEMGeneratorHostKeyProvider hostKeyProvider = new PEMGeneratorHostKeyProvider("app.pem");
hostKeyProvider.setAlgorithm("RSA");
```

and put

```
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(hostKeyProvider);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
import org.apache.sshd.common.util.security.bouncycastle.BouncyCastleGeneratorHostKeyProvider

...

server.setKeyPairProvider(new BouncyCastleGeneratorHostKeyProvider(Paths.get("ssh.pem")))
```

I have no idea how I generated the pem file..

Comment: isnt pem just private key tho?